# Disable gesture zoom in responsive

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, meta, mobile-device

I have a custom theme (`rwd` set as parent theme), in mobile view I want to disable gesture zoom through out the site. For this I have below code in `head.phml`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I also tried adding below code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

But none of the above seems working, anyone has idea how to disable gesture zoom?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried testing on different devices? Some device such as iPhones on iOS10+ completely ignore this as it results in terrible user experience.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari for more info

Comment: I have tried it with two different android devices with chrome browser

Comment: Also I checked some other sites in the same device and those were not having this problem, So it is not device issue I think.

Comment: Strange, has the `meta` tag updated in the code?

Comment: yes it is updated and visible in the source code

Comment: Try adding `minimum-scale=1.0` and setting `user-scalable` to 1. If that doesn't work then I've no idea sorry :(

Comment: tried this, still same. Thanks for answering